# specify target with gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, pugixml

I am trying to compile a library in linux with gcc. I want the lib to run on a different platform.

With configure, we normally use build and host. However, this library has no configure option. So I am writing my own code to compile lib using GCC. How I can specify the target machine as an option with GCC?

Comment: What are your host and target platforms?

Answer (score 5):

Unless the target is already possible with the current GCC (e.g. like the `-m32` option of GCC on x86-64 Linux) you cannot compile your code with your usual GCC.

You have to either download and install a GCC cross-compiler or compile (as a cross-compiler using the `--target=` option for ./configure) GCC from its source code.

Every GCC installation has one single (main) target.

BTW, some Linux distributions are packaging some GCC cross-compilers. On Debian I have `gcc-arm-none-eabi` (targeted for ARM) and `gcc-msp430`  (targeted for MSP430)